# Why is the execution logic of pnpm -w i in pnpm 8 different from that in pnpm7?

Tags: monorepo, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

When I run `pnpm -w i` on pnpm7, it only installs global dependencies (not workspace dependencies).

But on pnpm8, when I run `pnpm -w i` , it installs all workspace dependencies.

I would like to be able to use pnpm8 to install only global dependencies and then specify the workspace dependencies to install